# Only able to send WCSession message from watch to iphone, not the other way

Tags: swift, apple-watch, watchconnectivity

This is my first time trying out any watch functionality and having an issue where I can only send a message from the watch to the iPhone, but unable to send from iPhone to watch. I get to the .sendMessage method when the session is reachable but the didReceiveMessage log never fires in the interfaceController.

All I want to do is have a button on the watch that requests the latest count of some array in the viewController. I've tried sendUserInfo as well and got the same thing, one way communication. Any help would be appreciated.

xcode 8.1 swift 2.3 & 3(watch)

**View Controller**

in viewDidLoad

```
if WCSession.isSupported() {
    WCSession.defaultSession().delegate = self
    WCSession.defaultSession().activateSession()
}
```

For WCSessionDelegate & message

```
func session(session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWithState activationState: WCSessionActivationState, error: NSError?){
   print("Session Active: \(activationState), Error: \(error)")
}
func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : AnyObject]) {
    if (message["getCount"] as? String == "please"){
        print("The watch asked nicely") // this logs on watch button press
        if (WCSession.defaultSession().reachable) {
            print("isReachable") // this logs on watch button press
            WCSession.defaultSession().sendMessage(["yo":"count"], replyHandler: nil, errorHandler: nil)
        }

    }
}

func sessionDidBecomeInactive(session: WCSession){
    print("Phone session inactive")
}

func sessionDidDeactivate(session: WCSession){
    print("Phone session deactivated")
}
```

**InterfaceController**

```
@IBAction func refreshButton() {
    if(WCSession.isSupported()){
        WCSession.default().sendMessage(["getCount":"please"], replyHandler: nil, errorHandler: nil)
    }
}
@IBOutlet var registrationCount: WKInterfaceLabel!

override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
    super.awake(withContext: context)
}

override func willActivate() {
    super.willActivate()
    if WCSession.isSupported() {
        WCSession.default().delegate = self
        WCSession.default().activate()
    }
}

override func didDeactivate() {
    super.didDeactivate()
}

func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : Any]) {
    print("Cool phone sent me a message")
}
@available(iOS 9.3, *)
func session(_ session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState, error: Error?){
    print("Session Active: \(activationState), Error: \(error)")
}

func sessionDidBecomeInactive(session: WCSession){
    print("Watch session inactive")
}

func sessionDidDeactivate(session: WCSession){
    print("Watch session deactivated")
}
```

Comment: Welp, looks like print only works on the iPhone side not watch side...

Comment: Pay attention that message from iPhone to watch will be delivered only if watch app is foreground (isReachable will be true), but sending message from watch to iPhone will succeed even if iOS app is background.
https://developer.apple.com/reference/watchconnectivity/wcsession/1615683-isreachable


Consider using updateApplicationContext(_:) instead